# Using SQLDeveloper to connect to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

We are running SQL Developer v4.1.3.20 and would like to connect to a SQL Server 2014 database.

We have tried two third party JDBC drivers - the Microsoft one (sqljdbc42.jar) and jtds-1.3.1.

Although the jtds driver will give us the SQL Server tab in the New/Select Database Connection dialog, we cannot connect to the db. We think this might be because the jtds driver wants java 1.7 and this version of SQLDeveloper requires 1.8.

The Microsoft driver does not seem to work at all (no SQL Server tab).

The error we get is

> Failure - I/O Error: DB server closed connection

I've not been able to find any other questions with the same versions ... has anyone got this to work and know which driver to use?

Comment: We only support jTDS. Java 8 shouln't be a problem. Check the server logs - they sever is closing the connection, right?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith We may not have access to the server logs (we're several degrees removed ... one of those situations where we've been given the connection details and, at this stage, that's about it!). But definitely something to follow up! Thanks!

Comment: it's probably a security flag, causing your connection to be refused. ask them to give you the exact jdbc url to use, with any properties required.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Got some additional feedback - need to use SSL but not validate the certificate (it is self-signed) so I have used ssl=require but I'm still not managing to get a connection (Connection Reset error). I've sent the jTDS doco regarding the connection string properties to the people looking after SQL Server to get some feedback.

I am dropping ourhost.com:1433/dbname;ssl=require in the hostname field and leaving port blank. I think there must be another property required to sort out the connection reset error.

Comment: you can use the advanced connection type and manually write the jdbc url string there..might end up similar to these examples, except of course using jTDS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption